# What is going wrong with this theme when running Eclipse?

Tags: gnome, theme, eclipse

Please see this video to understand what I'm describing: [Weirdness in Eclipse - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVFHr26hHNc).

Essentially, when I use the "Ambiance Evolution" theme with Eclipse, it starts wiggling and doesn't stop, as weird as that sounds. I really like the theme, so I'd like to be able to use it, but this is kind of unacceptable. How can I fix this strange issue?

Comment: It looks like your theme has had too much black coffee and it's kind of hyper! Wait for the caffeine crash for it to chill out?

Comment: Yeah, man, it's _trippin_!